# Cannot replace characters from csv and save them in new file using python

Tags: python

I have a csv which has the following:

```
"DCA.P/C.05820","5707119001793","P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK MINI","5,4","Yes"
"DCA.P/C.05821","5707119001779","P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK","7,2","No"
"DCA.P/C.05823","5707119001762","P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK+","11,9","No"
```

I am trying to change the csv into:

```
DCA.P/C.05820;5707119001793;P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK MINI;5,4;Yes
DCA.P/C.05821;5707119001779;P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK;7,2;No
DCA.P/C.05823;5707119001762;P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK+;11,9;No
```

I am not sure if I started it correctly.

```
def mycontents():   
igecontents = []
with open(source_initial1, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1',newline='') as csvf:
  data = ""
  data = csvf.read().replace('\","', '\";"').replace('"','')

with open(source_initial2, 'w', encoding='utf-8',newline='') as csvf:
    reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        igecontents.append(row) 
return igecontents
```

I get an error not readable row

Comment: Why not read and write completely with `csv` module (with different configurations)?

Comment: I dont know how to do it , if you please show me

Comment: use `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` - without `csvf.read()`

Comment: You are using the `csv.reader` already. You just have to specify the right `delimiter` and `quoting` for source file. Then create a `csv.writer` with the different settings of the destination format. Then you can read each row and write it to the writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where `pandas` library comes with real power and conciseness:

with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)/[`pandas.Dataframe.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) one-liner:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=',').to_csv('output.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

The final `output.csv` contents:

```
DCA.P/C.05820;5707119001793;P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK MINI;5,4;Yes
DCA.P/C.05821;5707119001779;P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK;7,2;No
DCA.P/C.05823;5707119001762;P/C STEELSERIES SURFACE QcK+;11,9;No
```

Comment: So it will not confuse the comma of 5,4

Comment: @Evridiki the comma is inside a quoted string it will be fine with a read csv reader.

Comment: @Evridiki, it's smart enough to infer a quoted enties. But you can operate on `quoting, quotechar,  doublequote, escapechar` options for mentioned pandas routines as well

Comment: @Evridiki, that means you did it in wrong way or missed something. And make sure you have a "fresh" pandas installed (`pip install  --upgrade pandas`)

Comment: @Evridiki maybe first check if you read data - `df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=',')`  `print(df)`. Maybe this code is never run so it can't save it.

Comment: @Evridiki, if you at least try to follow the links I posted - you'll see the option `encoding` there

Comment: It is working, the problem with my csv data was that it contained some extra , so I got tokenizing error and I put error_bad_lines=False to skip them. But if I need them?

Comment: @Evridiki If you have error then show it in question. Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @Evridiki, if you have another csv input - you need to put it into the question's description and, as -@furas mentioned, all potential error messages if occurred

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to worry about comma - csv will care of it

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as file_in, open('output.csv', 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter=',')
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out, delimiter=';')
    for row in csv_in:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

or even using `writerows()` to write all rows

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as file_in, open('output.csv', 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter=',')
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out, delimiter=';')
    csv_out.writerows(csv_in)
```

Comment: I get UnicodeDecodeError charmap can't decode byte even if I put encoding='utf-8'

Comment: Then the file has a different encoding, but without seeing the offending byte and a bit of context, we can't know which one. This answer is correct, anyway; the error is unrelated. See also  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: always show full error in question. Maybe you have different encoding in file or maybe you have problem display it.